# reCaptcha Issues with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

I'm implementing reCaptcha, and I'm using an Ajax call to a PHP page of mine to check the validity of the captcha, without a page refresh.

I have this jQuery code:

```
$.post('php/captcha.php', $('#captchaPost').serialize(), function(data){
            if(data != "Valid")
            {
                $('#captchaError').show();
                $captchaFlag = "Invalid";
            }
            else
            {
                $('#captchaError').hide();
                $captchaFlag = "Valid";
            }
        });
```

And this PHP code for the post handler:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "1234567890";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                        $_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                        $_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) 
{
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
echo "Error";
} 

else 
{
echo "Valid";
}
?>
```

I checked the response using Firebug and the PHP script always returns "Error", even when I type in the correct Captcha. The form seems to POST correctly, according to the server, although I don't see how to check what was posted in the form. I am not using the PHP function to build the reCaptcha form; I got the HTML from Google's docs on this. Any help?

Comment: If you always get "Error", there must be something wrong with one of your parameters. Try echoing your params (the remote_addr header and the 2 form params) in your script instead, and see if you notice any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
function validateCaptcha()
{
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/captcha.php",
    data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&amp;recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(html != "Valid")
    {
        $('#captchaError').show();
        $captchaFlag = "Invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        $('#captchaError').hide();
        $captchaFlag = "Valid";
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like you were sending the data correctly in your jQuery.

**Edit**
Also make sure to call validateCaptcha() on the button.  For instance:

```
onSubmit="javascript:validateCaptcha()"
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but as soon as I put it in, I ran into another problem - my instance of reCaptcha isn't showing an actual captcha, just a blank space there.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment until now.  Since you accepted my answer I am assuming that it worked?